# How to generate an array of values in Simulink with varying max Limit

Tags: matlab, simulink

I feel that its really a dumb question to be even posted on forums. but i couldn't figure out the solution for simple problem which i am facing.

The Problem is I need to generate an array of values say [1:20] (or) [1:45] (or) [1:n] (or) even zeros(1,n) in SIMULINK ,so this n varies for every time step (using discrete mode simulation)...  I am getting this "n"  within each timestep in simulink model.

How would I get these values on simulink ?

Comment: Assuming you know `n` at each time step, then (without knowing exactly what you are doing) the easiest appraoch is most likely to use a `MATLAB Function` block ensuring that you configure it to have a variable sized output signal.

Comment: The problem came up as I was using MATLAB fucntion blocks in my model.  The function block gives variable sized outputs where I can only know the maximum upper bound of it.  So, i kept [9999 2] as my upperbound for the output of  function.  And coming back to values , If I have [135,2] values for one particular time step , it would just store those 135 and rest zeros . I thought I can strip out the zeros and just extract those [135 2] for my further processing and I am stuck at this point... This is my usecase @phil Goddard

Comment: I just gave another scalar output which is length of those required values , (in this ex: 135) which I am using to extract the first [135,2] values from my [9999,2] matrix